# how to make ng-show/ng-hide transition animation smoother

Tags: css, angularjs, css-transitions, servicenow

Our team is developing in ServiceNow and have created a page with a widget that embeds several other widgets in different tabs.  We're using the ng-show/ng-hide method to show/hide the specified tabs.  We've added some very basic transition css to fade in and out the chosen tab:

```
.animate-switch {
  transition: all linear 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}
.animate-switch.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

This works as expected-- the hiding tab fades out and clicked on tab fades in simultaneously, but when the fade out completes, there's a very noticeable jolt in the page to show the active tab.

Is there anything we can add to our css to make this transition a bit smoother?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you mean by "jolt"? Maybe a screen capture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest removing the "all" value in transition and just transition what you're actually using eg `opacity`. Watching everything that could possibly change is a bit expensive.

You might also want to force hardware acceleration (Your GPU is way better at this) by adding a 3d transform.

```
.animate-switch {
  transition: opacity linear 1s;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.animate-switch.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```